# Show/Render S3 data through CloudFront visually in a folder structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend, amazon-cloudfront

I have a private bucket with some `csv` files. I want to provide these files to the end user, but I do not want the end user to be logging into my S3 bucket console to download these files.

I can have a CloudFront distribution that allows access to these files only through the that distribution when I use Origin Access Identities (OAI). To fetch the files through cloudfront the user is expected to the know the full path of the file in S3.

In my case the user does not know the full path, or the name of the files. I am trying to find a way to render the `csv` files on S3 and provide them in some way to the user to download without having them go to the console. Ideally they would see a very basic folder structure that they can navigate and click on to download the files.

Does this require building a full web app? What is the easiest way?

Comment: You say that it is a private bucket, but you are also saying that you want users to access the files. So, do you want the data to be private, or do you want it to be publicly accessible (to anyone)? If it is only for a subset of people, how will the system identify the people who are permitted to access the files -- do they login to an app? Can you tell us more about these "end users" -- how do they know these files exist, how do they access them, how do you identify them? Please Edit your question to add these extra details rather than answering in a comment.